# Objects missing in view window

Tags: 3d-view

so this is really frustrating. Im not sure what is going on but on the left view windows you can only see the cushion, and on the right you can only see the chair. I dont know why they arent appearing in the same space. Ive already done alt H to unhide everything and they just dont appear in the same space anymore.

Any ideas?

[image]

This is after pressing the link button, just the chair appears still missing the cushion.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have unlinked the layers for the 3D views, so different layers are appearing in different 3D Views. To re-link them make sure the *Lock camera and layers* button is checked in the header of the 3D View:

[image]

You also have your objects on different layers, so upon enabling *Lock camera and layers*, one or more of your objects may disappear as the other 3D views will now only be displaying a single layer. The 20 squares, arranged in a grid, to the left of the red box in the screenshot are your layers. You can move objects between layers by selecting an object, pressing <kbd>M</kbd> and selecting a layer or view different layers by clicking one of the squares.

See the [Layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html) section of the Blender Manual for more information on managing and viewing layers.

Comment: I did that and the chair appears but the cushion is gone. :(

Comment: I figured it out i shift clicked the little dots so i could see them both. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Wolfgang I have updated the answer with more information anway.

Comment: @Wolfgang If this answer has helped you, feel free to mark it as 'accepted'. See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers